# How do I randomly select an image from photo gallery

Tags: android, image, file

I need to randomly select an image from a user's photo gallery. I don't mean starting an intent as in

```
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, GALLERY_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

No. I need to randomly select the image myself. Is there an efficient way to do this? Or do I have to actually read in all the image files and then randomly select a file, and then from the file get the image? By read all files, I mean with something as (snippet: I have a question not an answer)

```
void addFiles(final File parent, Set<File> images) {
        try {
            for (final File file : parent.listFiles()) {
                if (!file.getParent().contains("Android")) {

                    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                        if (isImageFile(file.getName())) {
                            images.add(file);
                        }
                    } else {
                        addFiles(file, images);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Please don't be too concerned with the code snippet. If I knew the best way, I would not be asking for help. Does anyone know an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code aside from the snippets. Unless you have a large number of files, you could very well read all the files into an array. Then generate a random number with 0 as lowest and arrayList.size()-1 as highest and get that index from the array.

Pseudo code:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

ArrayList<File> list = readFiles();
File randomFile = list.get(getRandomValue(0, list.size()-1));
...

public static int getRandomValue(int low, int high) {

    return random.nextInt((high - low) + 1) + low;

}
```